# Where can I get the data_corpus_irishbudget2010 used in the examples on the Quanteda site?

Tags: corpus, quanteda, dfm

I have been doing all the exercises in [Tutorials.Quanteda.io](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/), but the section on constructing a DFM uses a corpus called data_corpus_irishbudget2010 doesn't run. This is the code:

toks_irish <- tokens(data_corpus_irishbudget2010, remove_punct = TRUE)

dfmat_irish <- dfm(toks_irish)

print(dfmat_irish)

I get this error:

**Error in tokens(data_corpus_irishbudget2010, remove_punct = TRUE) : 
  object 'data_corpus_irishbudget2010' not found**

I have been able to load data_char_ukimmig2010 and data_corpus_inaugural. I just installed Quanteda this week. I also ran require(quanteda.corpora) and still can't use the data_corpus_irishbudget2010.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data object has been relocated to the new **quanteda.textmodels** package.  To access it, use:

```
data("data_corpus_irishbudget2010", package = "quanteda.textmodels")
```

Comment: Once I ran install.package("quanteda.textmodels") and require(quanteda.textmodels), the tutorial code ran as is. Thanks so much!